# How to make a ping command with a setTimeout function JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
    const m1 = await message.channel.send("Calculating ping (47%)").then(setTimeout(5000))
    const m2 = await m1.edit("Calculating ping (80%)").then(setTimeout(4000))
    const m3 = await m2.edit(`Finished Calculating ping! API Latency is ${Math.round(bot.ping)}ms`);

    m1
    m2
    m3
```

How do I make it so that when the person uses a ping command, it then edits to a progressive pinging process in a certain time like, "Calculating ping 47%", then it goes to "Calculating ping 90%" then it goes to "Finished Calculating ping!, Heres the ping ms"

Answer (score 0):

instread use like this

```
    module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    category: "info",
    description: "Returns latency and API ping",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const msg = await message.channel.send(` Pinging....`);

        msg.edit(` Pong!
        Latency is ${Math.floor((msg.editedTimestamp || msg.createdTimestamp) - (message.editedTimestamp || message.createdTimestamp))}ms
        API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
    }

}
```

pinging a message doesn't take much time ex 15ms so its better this way

Comment: yeah but i wanna make it dramatic